# parse server cosmosdb not returning results for GeoPoint

Tags: parse-platform, azure-cosmosdb, parse-server, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm investigating the feasibility of migrating mongodb hosted on mlab to azure cosmosdb. I have used the Parse Server on managed Azure services (ARM?) template from Microsoft.

I have found that my GeoPoint queries (e.g. 'field' near a point) are failing to return results, same code works fine on native mongodb.

Suspect that this is because the cosmosdb is missing a 2d index or it interprets spatial data differently.Can anyone confirm?

Is there a list of stuff that doesn't work properly for parse hosted on cosmosdb?